# Using go delve with google app engine standard & dev_appserver.py

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, delve

In the google release notes it says:

```
November 15, 2017
Go runtime notes

Updated Go SDK to 1.9.61
Add --go_debugging flag to dev_appserver.py to enable Delve debugging.
```

I'm using dev_appserver.py to fire up several services simultaneously, so that they all share the same datastore emulator, and it works great.

However, when I add that --go_debugging flag, I get lots of errors which I don't understand.  If anyone has insight, I'd be grateful.

I get these kinds of errors for each service it tries to build:

```
can't load package: package -N: unknown import path "-N": cannot find module providing package -N
can't load package: package -l: unknown import path "-l": cannot find module providing package -l
```

Is there maybe a problem with launching several services at once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Nov 2020:

With all the new changes to app engine being able to use standard go libraries at google APIs, now I can just run my go app locally without using dev_appserver, and let it attach to my local datastore emulator etc.  Because of that, and thanks to vscode, delve debugging works great (with the go extension).  So now I can step through my app engine standard go code.